# How to change background color with DocX (Microsoft Word) documents

Tags: c#, office-interop, novacode-docx

I am trying to change the background color (only for a few words) in a Word document.

I am using DocX (https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Examples/Program.cs), but I cannot find any methods/properties which allow me to do so.

Here is my code:

```
    var rb = new Formatting();
        rb.UnderlineColor = this.GetResultColor(stu.RespectfulBehavior);
        rb.FontColor = this.GetResultColor(stu.RespectfulBehavior);

templ.ReplaceText(PlaceHolders.RespectfulBehaviour.GetDisplayName(), "    ", newFormatting: rb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the DocX source code of the [Formatting](https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/Formatting.cs) in class I would say that you're looking for `Highlight`. So if you wanted something highlighted in blue

```
rb.Highlight = Highlight.blue;
```

**Edit:**
This seems to have been already answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141775/2039359

Comment: yep, after hours of searching and diving into the code, I found that it's actually the highlight I am looking for... Thank you for your answer :)